# Matrix with tuples outside and fractions inside spacing

Tags: spacing, matrices

I have the following Latex code which is a matrix with fractions inside and tuples outside.

```
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\newcommand{\matindex}[1]{\mbox{\scriptsize#1}}% Matrix index

\begin{equation}
  \begin{blockarray}{cccc}
   &  \matindex{(a,b)} & \matindex{(a,b)} & \matindex{(a,b)} \\
    \begin{block}{c(ccc)}
\matindex{(a,b)} & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} \\
\matindex{(a,b)} & \frac{24}{14} & \frac{36}{14} & \frac{1}{14} \\
\matindex{(a,b)} & \frac{8}{44}  & \frac{2}{44} & \frac{1}{1}
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
```

with output

[image]

I would like this to be formatted more like this, where the spacing is correct and the tuples on the top are rotated slightly

[image]

However, I cannot get this to work. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `nicematrix` package is simple:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{%
    code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle,
    code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle,
                    }
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
A = 
\begin{pNiceArray}[first-row,first-col]{ccc}
        &       (a,b)   &       (a,b)   &       (a,b)   \\
(a,b)   & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} \\
(a,b)   & \frac{24}{14} & \frac{36}{14} & \frac{1}{14}  \\
(a,b)   & \frac{8}{44}  & \frac{2}{44}  & \frac{1}{44}  \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate the headers, if you wish; I also add a way to raise a bit the entries in the outer column, so that they're centered with respect to the row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\newcommand{\rh}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}
\newcommand{\uh}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}
A =
\begin{pNiceArray}[first-row,first-col]{ccc}
           & \rh{(a,b)}    & \rh{(a,b)}    & \rh{(a,b)}   \\
\uh{(a,b)} & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} & \frac{12}{14} \\
\uh{(a,b)} & \frac{24}{14} & \frac{36}{14} & \frac{1}{14}  \\
\uh{(a,b)} & \frac{8}{44}  & \frac{2}{44}  & \frac{1}{44}  \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

The commands `\rh` and `\uh` are disposable, their meaning will be lost at the end of the display.

[image]